# How to Create Dynamic Value Which Can use Entire App

Tags: ios, return-value, globalization

Basiclly, I have a button which created value according to finish some math process like  +, - , /, *.  Question is when I get some value, I needed to use that value again when I press button second time.  Let me explain `Basicly`,

When I clicked button process like,

```
      int examplea  = [txt_example.text intValue];
      int exB = 5000;
      int exC = exB - examplea;
```

This is the first time I push the button, my lastest value is `exC` When I input text field another value and clicked it same process will start but one difference:

```
    int examplea = [txt_example.text intValue];
    int exB = exC;
    int exC ( this new value which will be calculated )  = exB - examplea;
```

How can I create process like this?

Comment: Your would store the value in exC as a data member of a class and the code that gets called when the button is pressed is a method of that class. Your profile says you are a software engineer yet your question implies you don't know what a class is and what they are used for? Therefore perhaps I do not understand your question.

Comment: I'm just new in IOS Dev. It could be much more easy if i would write some code on C#. It doesn't matter what my title is actually. But if you don't write your answer it's OK for me.

Comment: Give me a minute and I will do

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm just here for learning things. It's nice to people someone like you. Who could help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

in the .h file

```
@interface MyCalculator : NSObject
- (int) doCalculation;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int exB;
@end
```

in the .m file

```
    @implementation MyCalculator

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _exB = 5000;
    }
    return self;
}

    - (int) doCalculation
    {
        int examplea  = [txt_example.text intValue];
        int exC = self.exB - examplea;
        self.exB = exC;
        return exC;
    }
    @end



....
MyCalculator* myCalculator = [[MyCalculator alloc] init];

...

[myCalculator doCalculation];
```

This isn't the full solution as there are several questions about what your code will do, but it will illustrate the principle of how to do it.
The last line is what gets called when the button is pressed.

I don't know where txt_example.text is coming from, but it might be better if that is passed to doCalculation as a parameter.

Comment: Txt_example. Text is the text field which users can write input.  Thanks fir guidance I will try it

Comment: I try to solution which you wrote. But i think i didn't clear myself too you. But your solution give me perspective to solve my problem thanks anyway..